# How would i send a value from one jsp to another using the link

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page where I have a link to "Creation.jsp" for which I have to pass the id.

I have used the following inside the anchor tag

href=/home/Creation.jsp?rad=<%=id%>

When i use like this, the actual id value is being displayed in the URL of the browser.

My question is : i dont want to display the value in the URL but want to send a value through the link from one jsp to another.
How can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a link button of type submit and submit it via a form. In the form action give the name of the Creation.jsp page there you will be able to access the value if you have stored it in a invisible textbox.

```
<form action="Creation.jsp" method="post">

<input type= "hidden" value="<%=id%>" name="hdnId"/>

<input type="submit">

</form>
```

now on the Creation.jsp page get the value by request.GetParameter("hdnId");

Addition:
Put this in the servlet

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Creation.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

refer http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html

Comment: I have more than 6 links in my homepage, each link I have to send a different value to another jsp....

Comment: Those links wont be directing to the same page then you have to give each different values in different input type

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this.

Comment: For your situation as you dont want to show data in the url create a servlet where first the request will go there you can check which button was pressed then you can pass to different page using requestdispatcher.

Comment: So you only need only 1 hidden field holding your value which you can access from the required page